# Align several tabularx tables

Tags: tabularx, cv

trying to build my CV here with Latex. I have found a template, https://github.com/btskinner/tex_cv/blob/master/cv.tex. What I do not understand is why in the example below, the two tables are not aligned, although as far as I can see the code should align them? That's how it compiles for me:

[image]

How do I get the 2020 & XXXX as well as the "Something, somwhere" & test to be aligned? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcommand{\recentyear}{1900}  % artificially low year to include everything

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% HEADER STUFF (CAN LEAVE ALONE UNLESS YOU WANT TO PERSONALIZE)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------------
% Packages
% -------------------------------

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % for margins
\usepackage[american]{babel}      % for language

      % for reference sections


\usepackage{titlesec}             % to adjust section headers
\usepackage{tabularx}             % for fluid tables

% -------------------------------
% Macros


\newcommand{\RR}{\raggedright\arraybackslash} % left justified
\newcommand{\RL}{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}  % right justified

% for tables to keep consistent alignment across sections
\newcolumntype{\twocols}{>{\RR}p{1.25in}>{\RR}X}
\newcolumntype{\threecols}{>{\RR}p{1.25in}>{\RR}X>{\RL}p{1in}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Education}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{-1.5em}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}  
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{\threecols}
 2020 (expected) &Something, somewhere & Ph.D. \\ % or YYYY (expected)
 
\end{tabularx}


\section*{Grants and Scholarships}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{-1.5em}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}  
\end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{\threecols}
    YYYY & test & bb \\
    YYYY - YYYY & Fellowship & \$ AMOUNT \\ % if normal in your field
    
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the empty line between the first `\end{center}` and `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: So simple...thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use macros and no `tabularx`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
% -------------------------------
% Packages
% -------------------------------

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % for margins
\usepackage[american]{babel}      % for language

      % for reference sections


\usepackage{titlesec}             % to adjust section headers
\usepackage{tabularx}             % for fluid tables

\newcommand{\recentyear}{1900}  % artificially low year to include everything

\titleformat{\section}
 {\bfseries\Large}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}% no space
 {}% the title
 [\titlerule]

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% HEADER STUFF (CAN LEAVE ALONE UNLESS YOU WANT TO PERSONALIZE)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


% -------------------------------
% Macros

\newcommand{\twocolsection}[2]{%
  \section{#1}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{1.25in}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.25in-2\tabcolsep}
    @{}
  }
  #2
  \end{tabular}\par
}
\newcommand{\threecolsection}[2]{%
  \section{#1}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{1.25in}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2.25in-4\tabcolsep}
    wr{1in}
    @{}
  }
  #2
  \end{tabular}\par
}

\begin{document}

\threecolsection{Education}{
 2020 (expected) &Something, somewhere & Ph.D. \\ % or YYYY (expected)
}

\threecolsection{Grants and Scholarships}{
    YYYY & test & bb \\
    YYYY - YYYY & Fellowship & \$ AMOUNT \\ % if normal in your field
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might parametrize the width of the first and last column, in case the data for the specific CV doesn't fit.

This way you don't risk that the `tabular` is detached from the title.

---

A more polished version where the column widths (first and third) are parametrized, so you can change their size in the appropriate spot in the preamble. Also `\twocolsection` and `\threecolsection` have an optional argument which should be `L` (default) or `J`, for specifying left alignment (ragged right) or justification in the main column.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % for margins
\usepackage[american]{babel}      % for language
\usepackage{titlesec}             % to adjust section headers
\usepackage{array}

% customization of sections

\titleformat{\section}
 {\bfseries\Large}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}% no space
 {}% the title
 [\titlerule]

% main macros

\newlength{\firstcol}
\newlength{\thirdcol}

% helper column types
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}
\newcolumntype{J}[2]{%
  p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\twocolsection}[3][L]{%
  \section{#2}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #1{\firstcol}{2}
    @{}
  }
  #3
  \end{tabular}\par
}
\newcommand{\threecolsection}[3][L]{%
  \section{#2}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #1{\firstcol+\thirdcol}{4}
    wr{\thirdcol}
    @{}
  }
  #3
  \end{tabular}\par
}

%%% final customization
\setlength{\firstcol}{1.25in}
\setlength{\thirdcol}{1in}
%%%

\begin{document}

\threecolsection{Education}{
  2020 (expected) &Something, somewhere & Ph.D. \\ % or YYYY (expected)
}

\threecolsection{Grants and Scholarships}{
  YYYY & test & bb \\
  YYYY - YYYY & Fellowship & \$ AMOUNT \\ % if normal in your field
}

\twocolsection{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\twocolsection[J]{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another version where you can separate items in each list by some vertical space. One needs higher level methods to ensure that the space is added only between items, using `\addlinespace` provided by `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % for margins
\usepackage[american]{babel}      % for language
\usepackage{titlesec}             % to adjust section headers
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% customization of sections

\titleformat{\section}
 {\bfseries\Large}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}% no space
 {}% the title
 [\titlerule]

% main macros

\newlength{\firstcol}
\newlength{\thirdcol}

% helper column types
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}
\newcolumntype{J}[2]{%
  p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\twocolsection}{ O{L} m +m }
 {
  \section{#2}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #1{\firstcol}{2}
    @{}
  }
  \scw_cv_table:n { #3 }
  \end{tabular}\par
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\threecolsection}{ O{L} m +m }
 {
  \section{#2}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #1{\firstcol+\thirdcol}{4}
    wr{\thirdcol}
    @{}
  }
  \scw_cv_table:n { #3 }
  \end{tabular}\par
 }

\seq_new:N \l__scw_cv_rows_seq
\tl_new:N \l__scw_cv_last_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scw_cv_table:n
 {
  % get the rows
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__scw_cv_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % remove the last item if empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__scw_cv_rows_seq \l__scw_cv_last_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l__scw_cv_last_tl
   {% not blank, reinsert it
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__scw_cv_rows_seq \l__scw_cv_last_tl
   }
  % deliver the rows separated by \\ \addlinespace
  \seq_use:Nn \l__scw_cv_rows_seq { \\ \addlinespace }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% final customization
\setlength{\firstcol}{1.25in}
\setlength{\thirdcol}{1in}
%\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.5em} % this is the default in booktabs
%%%

\begin{document}

\threecolsection{Education}{
  2020 (expected) &Something, somewhere & Ph.D. \\ % or YYYY (expected)
}

\threecolsection{Grants and Scholarships}{
  YYYY & test & bb \\
  YYYY - YYYY & Fellowship & \$ AMOUNT \\ % if normal in your field
}

\twocolsection{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\twocolsection[J]{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\end{document}
```

Experiment with different values of `\defaultaddspace`.

[image]

For dealing also with subsections, I suggest a slightly different syntax that avoids some code duplication.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % for margins
\usepackage[american]{babel}      % for language
\usepackage{titlesec}             % to adjust section headers
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% customization of sections

\titleformat{\section}
 {\bfseries\Large}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}% no space
 {}% the title
 [\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\bfseries\normalsize}
 {}% no number
 {0pt}% no space
 {}% the title
 [\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}

% main macros

\newlength{\firstcol}
\newlength{\thirdcol}

% helper column types
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}
\newcolumntype{J}[2]{%
  p{\dimexpr\textwidth-(#1)-#2\tabcolsep\relax}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\twocol}{ m O{L} m +m }
 {
  #1{#3}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #2{\firstcol}{2}
    @{}
  }
  \scw_cv_table:n { #4 }
  \end{tabular}\par
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\threecol}{ m O{L} m +m }
 {
  #1{#3}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{
    @{}
    wl{\firstcol}
    #2{\firstcol+\thirdcol}{4}
    wr{\thirdcol}
    @{}
  }
  \scw_cv_table:n { #4 }
  \end{tabular}\par
 }

\seq_new:N \l__scw_cv_rows_seq
\tl_new:N \l__scw_cv_last_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scw_cv_table:n
 {
  % get the rows
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__scw_cv_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % remove the last item if empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__scw_cv_rows_seq \l__scw_cv_last_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l__scw_cv_last_tl
   {% not blank, reinsert it
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__scw_cv_rows_seq \l__scw_cv_last_tl
   }
  % deliver the rows separated by \\ \addlinespace
  \seq_use:Nn \l__scw_cv_rows_seq { \\ \addlinespace }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% final customization
\setlength{\firstcol}{1.25in}
\setlength{\thirdcol}{1in}
%\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.5em} % this is the default in booktabs
%%%

\begin{document}

\threecol\section{Education}{
  2020 (expected) &Something, somewhere & Ph.D. \\ % or YYYY (expected)
}

\threecol\section{Grants and Scholarships}{
  YYYY & test & bb \\
  YYYY - YYYY & Fellowship & \$ AMOUNT \\ % if normal in your field
}

\twocol\subsection{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\twocol\subsection[J]{Whatever}{
  YYYY & something long to need being split across lines; let's just
         write long enough nonsense and see
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was just starting to puzzle over the various lengths of the column!

Comment: @SCW I added a more polished version.

Comment: Thanks! I just got started on tables in Latex, so this is very helpful. May I ask, how can I marginally increase the space between different column lines, so it's a bit easier to read?

Comment: @SCW I added another version for spacing the items in each list.

Comment: How could one adapt the second solution for the \subsection level, too?

Comment: @SCW I added a proposal

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a more complete version of this CV template anywhere on this site? It looks cleaner than most of the available packages